# Entity Framework:Foreign Key as part of Composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have requirements where we are required to use a foreign key as a part of Composite key in another table.
e.g.

```
Public Primary_Class{
    public int pkey{get; set;}
    public string Misc{get; set;}
}


Public dependent_Class{
    *public int dkey {get; set;} /*Column 1 of Primary key*/
    public int pkey{get; set;}  /*Cloumn 2 of PK as well as FK to Primay_Class*/

    pubic string data{get; set;}
}
```

Could please help me achieve this in Entity Framework 6.0

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you ever tried but still I'm answering.

In Entity Framework you can achieve this by using [Entity Framework Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**Here is complete solution:**

```
public class Primary_Class
{
    [Key]
    public int pkey { get; set; }
    public string Misc { get; set; }
}
public class dependent_Class
{
    [Key]
    public int dkey { get; set; } //*column 1 of Primary key*/

    [ForeignKey("Primary_Class")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int pkey { get; set; }  //*Cloumn 2 of PK as well as FK to Primay_Class*
    public string data{get; set;}
}
```